# sponge from moreutils - what's the difference to shell redirect? useful examples?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection, utilities

```
> brew install moreutils                                                          
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/moreutils-0.55.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz    
######################################################################## 100.0%               
==> Pouring moreutils0.55.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz       
  /usr/local/Cellar/moreutils/0.55: 67 files, 740K
```

> sponge reads standard input and writes it out to the specified file.
>   Unlike a shell redirect, sponge soaks up all its input before writing
>   the output file. This allows   constructing pipelines that read from
>   and write to the same file.

I don't understand. Please give me some useful examples.

What does *soaks up* mean?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=sponge

Comment: Another example is `expand foo.txt | sponge foo.txt`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33639324/1959808

Comment: tl;dr `sponge` "soaks up" its input *before* truncating the output file

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assume that you have a file named `input`, you want to remove all line start with `#` in `input`. You can get all lines don't start with `#` using:

```
grep -v '^#' input
```

But how do you make changes to `input`? With standard POSIX toolchest, you need to use a temporary file, some thing like:

```
grep -v '^#' input >/tmp/input.tmp
mv /tmp/input.tmp ./input
```

With shell redirection:

```
grep -v '^#' input >input
```

will truncate `input` before you reading from it.

With `sponge`, you can:

```
grep -v '^#' input | sponge input
```

Comment: You actually can read and write a file at the same time safely as long as the bytes are only being transformed, using the `<>` operator.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Yes, I mean without making it corroupt

Comment: @ChrisDown: Let me remove that sentence to avoid confusing. I actually mean when using `<>file`, you open file for reading and writing but you actually don't write anything to file.

Comment: Did you try it? :-) `<>` has no problem writing to a file, try it for yourself: `printf foobar >q; printf bar 1<>q` results in `barbar`.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Of course, But I mean in the context of reading and writing to file, like `<file >file`. Continue with your above example, `printf '\nfoo' >q; grep bar <>q` make `q` un-changes.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Sorry, mis-typing `printf '\nfoo' >>q;`

Comment: Because `grep bar` there doesn't output anything :-) If it did, it would write.

Comment: @ChrisDown: Even if `grep` output anything, it never goes to `q`.

Comment: @cuonglm You need  to explicitly specify the FD with`1<>`, not just `<>`. That's why your example doesn't work.

Comment: @ChrisDown: `grep` will ignore if using `1<>`

Comment: I think the point that @ChrisDown is trying to make is that `<>` doesn't truncate a file, but merely replaces its existing bytes with the new output. If the new output is too short, you'll have leftover garbage at the end of the file. But if the new output is long enough, there's no risk.

Answer (score 20):

The [moreutils home page](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) itself documents a typical use case:

```
sed "s/root/toor/" /etc/passwd | grep -v joey | sponge /etc/passwd
```

Here, /etc/passwd is both being written to and read to, and is being modified. Without sponging up stdin before writing, /etc/passwd might be corrupted (as the file changed during reading).

Comment: And that would be a good example on the moreutils page, if it had explained the way you did :-)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest example of `sponge` I've ever read:

```bash
$ cat file1 
I
You
Me
We
Us
```

To sort it, you can simply

```bash
$ sort file1 > file1_sorted
```

However, with `sponge`, you can read from and write to the same file.

```bash
$ sort file1 | sponge file1
```

without requiring the temporary file `file1_sorted`. This is because `sponge` first read from STDIN, and then write it out to `STDOUT`, in separate steps, thus avoiding corrupting the file as it is changed during the reading.

Comment: Using `sort` as an example is a bit awkward, as you would rather use `sort -o file1 file1` to sort the file in place (i.e., `sort` already has this "built-in", so to speak).