# How to apply multiple commands to a CSV file without undoing the previous command?

Tags: bash, sed, command-line

I'm super new to using command line so sorry if this seems like a silly question! I'm trying to edit a CSV file in terminal with these set of commands:

```
(head -n 1 canine_genes_v2.csv && tail -n +2 canine_genes_v2.csv | sort -t, -k2,2n)

sed ‘s/plus/+/g’ canine_genes_v2.csv

sed ‘s/minus/-/g’ canine_genes_v2.csv

cut -d, -f 1,2,3,4,5,6 canine_genes_v2.csv

perl -p -e 's/,/\t/g' canine_genes_v2.csv
```

My problem is that every time I apply a command it undoes the previous command, I have figured out if I run each command separately and save the output to a different file I'm able to see the change using the md5sum command. But my problem is I want to apply all these commands at the same time to the same file.

Comment: It may also benefit the reader if you put one or two lines of your csv file into your question so we really know what you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

None of those commands undoes anything, they simply don't change the file at all. Apply one of your commands and see that the file didn't change. Those commands like `head`, `sed` and `cut` *read* the file, perform their changes and send the output to `stdout`, e. g. the shell session.

If you want to actually change the file, you could

- pipe output of one command to the next one
- use `sed` with the `-i`  option, if your `sed` version offers it
- redirect output of each command to a temporary file with `> temp-filename`
  which can be used as input for the next stage

Comment: Another possibility: [sponge](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207921/108618).