# Why doesn't this function work for soak up stdin?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

This:

```
echo 'some text' > file.txt
cat file.txt > file.txt
```

Obviously gives me an empty file.

But to my surprise also:

```
cat2 () {
    cat "$@" > tmp.txt
    cat tmp.txt
    return $?
}

echo 'some text' > file.txt
cat2 file.txt > file.txt
```

it gives me an empty file, even though the file `tmp.txt` has been cated, different from `file.txt`.

This method doesn't work either!:

```
echo 'some text' > file.txt
cat file.txt | cat2 > file.txt
```

Why is the file emptied anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate, or at least closely related: [sponge from moreutils - what's the difference to shell redirect? useful examples?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/207919)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your command

```
cat2 file.txt > file.txt
```

will create a new empty `file.txt` *before* it calls the `cat2` function.

So by the time `cat2` is run the file is empty and so `cat`ing it will result in empty output.

If it helps break down the order of operation, what you've done is

- create a file file.txt with content
- create a new blank file file.txt
- run cat2 with output to file.txt

This is because the redirect operator occurs before the `cat2` execution.

Comment: "will create a new empty `file.txt`" – New, only if the file does not exist yet. If `file.txt` exists (and this is the case here) then it will be truncated to zero size. The inode number will stay. Open file descriptions (if any) associated with the "old" file will see the "new" file because it's the same file.

Answer (score 1):

This construct does work (it uses `tr` as a sample operation):

```
{ 'rm' -f File.txt && tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' > File.txt; } < File.txt
```

The input redirection `< File.txt` assigns the file as stdin to the statements in braces first, before executing anything within the block.

Removing the file inside the block does not remove the contents, because the file has an open file descriptor. Note the `rm` is quoted to avoid the case where it might be aliased, e.g. with the `-i` option.

The output redirection creates a new output file (inode) with the same name as the original. When the `tr` terminates, the new file is closed.

Finally, the input redirection completes, it now has no connections via directories or file descriptors, and its resources are freed up.

Edit based on Stéphane Chazelas' excellent comments:

(a) The `rm` should have the `-f` option, to avoid all prompts and errors.

(b) The `tr` should use the Locale-independent character classes.

(c) The new File.txt is independent from the old one, with different inode number, birth time and possible ownership, permissions, acl or other extended attributes. It also replaces a symlink with a plain file and would detach a hard link, leaving the original data under a different path name.

Comment: `rm` may still prompt the user without `-i` like when asked to remove a non-writable file. `'rm'` will bypass aliases (unless there's also an alias for `'rm'` of course), but not functions (like a `rm() { if ...; then rm -i "$@"; ...; }`). Better to use `{ rm -f File.txt && tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'; } < File.txt` here

Comment: Would be worth noting that you get a brand new `File.txt` independent from the old one, with different inode number, birth time and possible ownership, permissions, acl or other extended attributes. It also replaces a symlink with a plain file and would detach a hard link

Comment: Note that the file *must* be read via a shell redirection outside of the `{}` for this to work reliably. If you use something like `cat File.txt | { 'rm' -f File.txt && ...`, the `rm` command may happen to execute first and delete the file before `cat` (or whatever) can open it. The example in this answer does not have this problem, but you need to be careful not to change it too much...